# Why does html body have overflow?

Tags: html, css

I am learning front-end development by trying to clone https://mozilladevelopers.github.io/playground/ . Everything is fine, except that in devtools, `<body>` element has overflow, which can be traced down to overflow in `<header>` and `<section class="home">`. I am still trying to figure out exactly what is causing the overflow.

Apparently, removing `<img>`, `<h1>`, and `<p>` from the `<section class="home">` fixes this.

This is the demo on codepen: https://codepen.io/yahyamateen2/pen/ExoOGbp . Also, my browser is Mozilla Firefox 99.0, in case that is useful to know. Thanks in advance for any help or guidance.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Antonia", sans-serif;
  font-size: 3.8rem;
  line-height: 4.8rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
}

p {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: 2.4rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}

a {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

button {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

ul,
ol {
  list-style: none;
}

/* Layout */
.home {
  background-color: #306ffd;
  background-image: linear-gradient(60deg, #306efe, #003ab7);
  padding-top: 8rem;
  padding-bottom: 14.4rem;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.home > img:first-child {
  width: 80px;
}

.home > img:first-child,
.home p {
  margin-bottom: 4.8rem;
}

.home p {
  margin-top: 2.4rem;
}

.download-button {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: 2.4rem;
  color: #306ffd;
  padding: 1.6rem 2.4rem;
  border-radius: 5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease;
}

.download-button:focus,
.download-button:active,
.download-button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.download-button img {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.home svg {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
 <section class="home">
    <img src="https://mozilladevelopers.github.io/playground/static/ffde-logo.0a69ffe8.png" alt="" />
    <h1>Firefox DevTools Playground</h1>
    <p>Learn, build, improve, and create with Firefox DevTools.</p>
    <a
      href="https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/developer/?utm_source=moz-playground&amp;utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_content=index-hero"
      target="_blank"
    >
      <button class="download-button">
        <img
          src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"
          alt="Arrow pointing down"
        />Firefox Developer Edition
      </button>
    </a>
    <svg width="100%" height="47px" viewBox="0 0 1440 47" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <path
          d="M0,0.0577405639 C117.504588,18.44359 269.602477,22.1720696 456.293666,11.2431795 C562.076057,5.05068514 730.784198,0.911127653 885.297232,3.27366179 C1157.17617,7.43074321 1386.98062,21.3276838 1440,38.3891927 L1440,46.9388979 L0,46.9388979 L0,0.0577405639 Z"
          fill="#FFFFFF"
        ></path>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </section>
```

Comment: I am sorry for my poorly written and not well researched question. I did try searching online, but since I am new to web development, I do not have the right vocabulary to search correctly. Most search results are telling to set overflow: hidden, but I want to find out what is causing it. Also, I did mention that the problematic lines are the ones containing the image, h1, and paragraph - so that should be the minimal error cause. I did post the entire code, because I think the problem could be elsewhere. I am really sorry if this is not the correct way to ask question.

Comment: The question is ok, it is just we need the code to be HERE instead of elsewhere if at all possible. So you can click [edit] then the button shaped like `[<>]` and fill the panes with example code. Then click TIDY and save. Links grow stale or disappear.

Comment: Alright, after some trying I finally got this to work. The example is shown above. I did change the image, because the original one had base64 code which was too long. Also, only section with class home (which I suspect to be the problem) is shown. For full example, the codepen link is there as well.

Comment: So what is the issue exactly? the image fits nicely when full screen and I cannot scroll in any size. You mention devtools? Is the issue only what you see in devtools?

Comment: Yes! Visually everything works perfectly. The only issue is that I see `overflow` tag on the `<body>` element in the DEVTOOLS. I just wanted to know what is causing the overflow.

Comment: Just open devtools right now, and inspect the `<iframe>` above when you run the code snippet. With the `<body>` inside this `<iframe`> you will see `overflow` next to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it cames frow html tag.
[image]

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply. But can you explain it a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

It’s likely even a bug, like if your image or any element size is more than your body size or screen size then you might face that error so if you resize your image/SVG/tag/element then may not face that error, Since if you do **overflow: hidden;** rather than **overflow-x: hidden;** – it stops it.
It’s just more common and practical to use **overflow-x.**

```
*{
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

If you are again facing this error after applying the solution then you can add some javaScript. for javascript, you can comment below my answer--->
Hope You got it!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. But my problem is not how to handle overflow, but WHAT IS CAUSING it.